# Winform x coordinate is slightly offset

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I'm having trouble with positioning my windows form. 
I use this code to make it appear in the left corner, though it seems to be slightly offset from left corner, like 4-5 pixels.

The strange thing I've noticed is that if I set FormBorderStyle to None, it appears correctly.

The whole code of my form:

```
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.Manual;
        this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
```

[This is how it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhU1K.png)

Comment: You did not post the correct snippet.  Move your mouse over the gap.  What does the mouse cursor look like?  My crystal ball says that you never realized that Win10 uses transparent borders.

Comment: @HansPassant oh, you're right, I'd never guessed that. Thank you!